# converting messy date string to dateTime object in c#

Tags: c#, string

How can I convert the String `20120313` to a `DateTime` object that holds the value `13-Mar-2012`?

I fetch it as

```
DataEffectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date_id"]);
```

But it fails here already (converting to 1/1/2001)

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert 20120313 or 13-Mar-2012?

Comment: Just one comment - I view 20120313 as a somewhat *less* messy format than 13-Mar-2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "yyyyMMdd",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then if you want it as "13-Mar-2012", you need:

```
string reformatted = date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

... optionally passing in whatever culture you want to use for the month names etc.

(Another alternative is to use my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), which allows you to parse this as *just a local date*, without any concerns about what time it will use, time zones etc.)

Answer (score 2):

When you have a particular format in mind, `ParseExact` is helpful:

```
string s = "20120313";
var when = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

There's also an overload that accepts multiple candidate formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string date = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["date_id"], "yyyyMMdd", new CultureInfo("en"));
```